React Native multiple projects path problem
I have an app in React native. I have frontend and backend in same parent folder. Firstly, everything worked but now I have a problem with sequelize and SQLite database so I have to use Sequelize methods directly in my app.
So, in a file I have this:
import { SignGroup } from "../../../api/models/signGroup.js";

export async function getSignGroups() {
  try {
    const data = await SignGroup.findAll();
    return data.map((group) => group.toJSON()); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch sign groups: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

And it says:

I'm 100% sure that my path is correct because when i click on the path, it leads me to my file. I also tried using link from npm to link my projects but it doesn't work.
You can also see my folder structure here:


Are you trying the call function of api folder from your app folder?.
As much as I know, you may have bundling problems because React Native does not know about the files outside of your folder. I recommend using a monorepo structure. The example tool for this might be a Turborepo, which I have been using for a long time. You can check this link to learn how to add turborepo to your existing project.
Also, I wrote a blog post about monorepos in general. You can read it from here to get more information about monorepo structure.

Yes I am, I will check your article, it looks useful.
